# Why are nullable boolean values not comparable with the shorthand if(boolean)?

Tags: c#

Why can I compare nullable boolean values in C# like this:

```
bool? test = true;
if (test==true)
   //do somethign
```

but not like this:

```
bool? test = true;
if (test)
   //do somethign
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` statement in C# can only take a `bool` parameter.

`Nullable<bool>` is not the same as `bool`, and `null` is neither `true` nor `false`.

If you know your `bool?` has a value, you can use:

```
if (test.Value)
    //do something
```

Comment: And if you _don't_ know if it has a value, use `test.GetValueOrDefault()`: if it has a value, it will use it. If it doesn't, it will use `false`.